# I am not able to use vector header file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11

I want to use vector header file but I guess there is an error in it. I have attached the image file containing the error. When ever I run this code I get the error shown in the image. Please tell me how to resolve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
vector<vector<int>> rmat;
vector<int> r = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    rmat[i][j] = r[j];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        cout << rmat[i][j] << "\t";
    cout << "\n";
}


_getch();
return 0;
}
```

[image: Error on runtime]

Comment: You instantiated the `rmat` vector but didn't specify a size, therefore none was allocated, and you're accessing memory that does not exist yet.

Comment: Your `rmat` is empty, yet you try to access elements in it (`rmat[i][j]`).

Comment: i have to assign a rmat vector first. can i initialized using a variable

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message:

> vector subscript out of range

You have created an empty vector,

```
vector<vector<int>> rmat;
```

and then access its nonexisting elements,

```
rmat[i][j] = r[j];
```

which results in this undefined behaviour which in you case resulted in a helpful exception being thrown.

Grab [a good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the basics first.